# Add button to teams bot message extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams, chatbot

[image: screenshot of teams-bot]

Above is the picture of message extension in teams-bot. Can I add a button on the left side of the title shown in the picture? I used herocard here I also tried the adaptive card but it doesn't show here. Please help me, is this possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

We can not add the button on left side of the title for a Hero Card/Adaptive Card in Messaging Extension search result.

You can raise a user voice: [User Voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new)